# Ways to learn mathematical analysis.

Tags: analysis, education

I'm studying mathematical analysis, more specifically differential calculus in $\mathbb{R}^n$, my main problems is that I didn't realize what is the best way to abbord some exercises, like what definition of differentiability is the best to use.
Would you please give some advices for gain intuition?

Comment: Your question is unclear (and is likely off topic).  At minimum, could you give some examples?

Comment: Buy a textbook, typically universities have associated stores. You can learn it from the textbook. If you can't understand something, you can ask that question here on the site.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: It all depends on the course level. For example, in engineering, it usually suffices to know that for a function $\;f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m\;$, if all its partial derivatives (of first order) exist at a point and are continuous at some neighborhood of that point then $\;f\;$ is differentiable there. This is a sufficient condition but not a necessary one. In a course in mathematics it is customary to solve exercises showing the condition isn't necessary, though.

Comment: Probably there is no universal advice suitable for any exercise. However, I believe that some users can give you great insights if you post particular examples explaining what the troubles are for that specifc case.